# SwiftUI Simple ForEach multiple errors does not conform to View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to wrestle SwiftUI and either something is corrupt with my version of Xcode or I'm doing something wrong. I'm trying to loop through an array of social networks and it's not looping through. The error messages I get are:

**Referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'SocialNetwork' conform to 'View'**

**Generic struct 'List' requires that 'SocialNetwork' conform to 'View'**

```
struct SocialNetwork: Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
let type: NetworkType
let url: String
let icon: String

}

struct ChartView: View {
    
var networks = [SocialNetwork(type: .Instagram, url: "", icon: "")]

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(networks) { net in
                    net
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm confused as to why a simple struct would need to conform to View when it's just an array of identifiable?

Comment: Within your ForEach, you are trying to add a 'net' to the screen, which is a data point and not a View component. You need put the net data into an object, such as a Text().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ForEach` is a view container, so inside it there should be some view, but your `net` is a model (instance of `SocialNetwork`). Put there some list row view presenting one *network*, like

```
        List {
            ForEach(networks) { net in
                Label(net.url, image: net.icon)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the type SocialNetwork is not conforming to View the compiler warning is correct. You could try to display the url of each SocialNetwork in your ForEach by replacing `net` with `Text(net.url)`. Just as an example to make it compile